# ASP.Net MVC Identity 2.0 - Unexpected Logging users out after frequent application recycling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-identity-2

I have an issue with Identity 2.0 on Asp.NET MVC 5 project.
I am not using sessions, just the basic out of the box cookie based features.

My shared server currently recycles the application at a high frequency.
when this happens all the users get logged out.

The ApplicationCookie in the HttpContext.Request.Cookies remains the same but you get redirected to the login page and all identity.user properties are no longer there.

Is this normal and what sort of work rounds are there for maintaining logins after recycling?

Any advice would be really appreciated.
Is this a cache or machinekey issue?

(the website has plesk IIS interface so I don't have full control over it)

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure why the server is restarting the application regularly as none of the settings reflect this.  However found the reason for the users being logged out is due to identity 2 using a machine key that gets refreshed everything is resets the app